# If $f(x)=\begin {cases} x^a\sin (1/x) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x =0 \end {cases}$ is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$ find $a$

Tags: limits, derivatives

If $$f(x)=\begin {cases} x^a\sin (1/x) & x\not =0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end {cases}$$ is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$ find $a$.

Since the function is continuous
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^a \sin \left(\frac 1x\right) =0.$$

Function is not differentiable at $x=0$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {h^a \sin (\frac 1h)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0} h^{a-1} \sin \left(\frac 1h\right)$$ must not exist.

How do I find the interval of $a$ from these two results?

Comment: For easier understanding take ${1}/{x} = t$. You should be able to analyse where the limits do or do not exist. $t$ will of course now tend to infinity.

Comment: That "$\sin(1/x)$" is a red herring.  Take any function that is (only) bounded at $x=0$, it leads to the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: in general for

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^a \sin \left(\frac 1x\right) =0,$$

we must have $a>0$ because $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ has oscillatory nature as $x$ approaches zero. To remove this the power of $x$ must be $>0$ .

Thus from your continuity condition $a>0$ and for second limit not to exist $a\le1$ or $a\in(0,1]$.

Comment: I still haven’t understood why $a$ has to to have those specific values. Why does $a$ need to be $>0$ for the limit to exist and $\le 1$ for limit to not exist?

Comment: if a<0 then the limit would approach infinity try graphing it you will see the behavior of function

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $f$ be a bounded function, that is $ |f| \le M$, and let $g$ be a function with $\text{lim}_{x_0} g = 0$. What can you tell about the limit of $f\cdot g$ at $x_0$?

Answer (score -1):

Continuity implies $a > 0$ because otherwise $x^a \sin \left(\frac 1x\right)$ would go to infinity.

Non-differentiable implies $a \leq 1$ because the function's derivative $f'(x) = x^{a-2}(ax\sin \left(\frac 1x\right)-\cos \left(\frac 1x\right))$ then goes to -infinity on the right and +infinity on the left of $x=0$, making the function non-differentiable.

I don't think your method of proving non-differentiable was the best.